# Validate value using regexp

Tags: jquery, regex

I have no experience with regular expressions but i need to validate some value using jquery. After researching i found some solutions and i'have written a script.

I need to implement following rule:

String should contain at least one letter (uppercase or lowercase), one digit, one special character and it should be between 5 and 10 length.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
                var value = $('#someValue');
                if (!/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).{5,10}+$/.test(value)) {
                    alert('validation error');
                    return false;
                }
            })
```

i dont know am i right or wrong, need some advices from gurus=)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `+` after `.{5,10}` and use:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[_\W]).{5,10}$/
```

Otherwise `.{5,10}+` will cause an error in Javascript as there is no possessive quantifier in JS regex.